# C++" no match for operator<<" when printing a std::vector<std::pair>

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, cout, std-pair

I want to print the vector dicVec in order to check if everything is as I want. But I can´t. I already looked it up, but nothing helped.

This is my current code:

```
void Translate::read(){
    int i = 0;

    std::ifstream dic("ende.dic");
    if (dic.is_open())
    {
        std::string dicLine;
        while (std::getline(dic, dicLine)){
            std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> dicVec;
            std::pair<std::string, std::string> dicPair;
            std::size_t pos = dicLine.find(";");
            dicPair.first = dicLine.substr(0, pos);
            //std::cout << dicPair.first << " : ";
            dicPair.second= dicLine.substr(pos+1);
            //std::cout << dicPair.second << std::endl;
            std::cout << dicVec[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("File could not be opened");
    }
}
```

I also tried to print it using this:

```
std::cout << dicVec.at(i);
```

and this:

```
for (auto i = dicVec.begin(); i != dicVec.end(); ++i)
    std::cout << *i << ' ';
```

But there´s always this error:

```
no match for operator<<
```

What do I have to do in order to print my vector?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to print out a `std::pair`, but there is no standard `operator<<` implemented for `std::pair`, so you will have to write you own.

Even if you fix that, your code will still fail, because `dicVec` is empty when you call `std::cout << dicVec[i];`  You are not adding `dicPair` to `dicVec` before printing the contents of `dicVec`.  In fact, `dicVec` should be declared *above* the loop, not *inside* of it.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
typedef std::pair<std::string, std::string> stringPair;
typedef std::vector<stringPair> stringPairVec;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const stringPair &p) {
    out << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
    return out;
}

std:ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const stringPairVec &vec) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
        out << vec[i];
    }
    return out;
}

void Translate::read(){

    std::ifstream dic("ende.dic");
    if (!dic.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("File could not be opened");
    }

    stringPairVec dicVec;
    std::string dicLine;

    while (std::getline(dic, dicLine)) {
        std::size_t pos = dicLine.find(";");
        stringPair dicPair = std::make_pair(
            dicLine.substr(0, pos),
            dicLine.substr(pos+1)
        );
        dicVec.push_back(dicPair);
    }

    std::cout << dicVec;
}
```

Or, in C++11 and later, you can do this instead:

```cpp
using stringPair = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;
using stringPairVec = std::vector<stringPair>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const stringPair &p) {
    out << p.first << " : " << p.second << "\n";
    return out;
}

std:ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const stringPairVec &vec) {
    for (const auto &p : vec) {
        out << p;
    }
    return out;
}

void Translate::read(){

    std::ifstream dic("ende.dic");
    if (!dic.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("File could not be opened");
    }

    stringPairVec dicVec;
    std::string dicLine;

    while (std::getline(dic, dicLine)) {
        std::size_t pos = dicLine.find(";");
        dicVec.emplace_back(
            dicLine.substr(0, pos),
            dicLine.substr(pos+1)
        );
    }

    std::cout << dicVec;
}
```